# Would protecting the frontend (React.js) part of a project with Keycloak be enough?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, keycloak

My javascript project is of two parts: frontend (React.js) and backend (node.js). I was wondering if I integrated Keycloak to frontend only, would backend be secured too? Or should I try to integrate it to both of them?

Comment: Hello, you must give little more detail about "but it didn't work". did the login redirection process done ? are there any error occured while keycloak login process ? What is the error case or have you any log about it ?

Comment: Well, normally the frontend opens a login page. When I connected Keycloak to backend, the frontend login page opened again.

Comment: If i clearly understand you usecase. You have two keycloak client configuration for both frontend and backend. I think that frontend token do not pass to backend successfully. As default, "Authorization" uses for pass access token to server on http requests. Please make sure, your header of  frontend request contains "Authorization header like bearer JWT_TOKEN". If backend do not resolve valid token on request, it will try to redirect login page again. (check you request from network tab of developer console of your browser and make sure your request contains "Authorization" header)

Comment: Well I actually don't have two configurations. I only configured it at backend and I am trying to access frontend with that

Answer (score 3):

I'll basically do this:

- Protect the frontend with standard OAuth2 authorization code grant flow, creating a specific PUBLIC client for the frontend and following the Keycloak guides to leverage the Authentication flow and to leverage the Keycloak's login pages and so on.
- For the backend side you should also create a new bearer only (or confidential) client in order to validate tokens coming from the frontend. There are a lot of examples on how to do this in Java and other languages. The backend client, if set to "confidential" can also be used by the backend to get new tokens from Keycloak and to contact other Keycloak-protected services